# How can I test a rejected payment with Paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm using Paypal Express Checkout with IPN service and I need to test what's happends when paypal returns a rejected payment.

Comment: rejected as in processor decline that sort of thing ?

Comment: I don't understad what you mean. What I need is to send a payment to my api that has `payment_status: failed` with Paypal Sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Payment rejected does not generate an IPN. IPN only generated when the payment was success.

If the payment rejected after success, then it will generate an IPN. For any occasion, the payment must success before IPN generated for rejected transactions.

payment_status in IPN could be vary, but the payment must first be successful.

You can read about the payment_status in IPN [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/).

Comment: How can I send to my API a payment with `payment_status: failed` in the sandbox? How can I simulate it?